# Leader Not Available Kafka in Console Producer with ssl+acl configrations

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

**I am trying to use kafka 0.11.0.1 with ssl+acls**.  My configurations are here below.

server.properties:

```
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092,SSL://127.0.0.1:9093
advertised.listeners=SSL://127.0.0.1:9093
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400  
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600 
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
ssl.keystore.location=/u/jewel/ssl+acl/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1/kaf-new/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
ssl.truststore.location=/u/jewel/ssl+acl/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1/kaf-new/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
```

producer.properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9093
compression.type=none
ssl.keystore.location=/u/jewel/ssl+acl/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1/prod/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test123
ssl.key.password=test123
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/u/jewel/ssl+acl/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1/kaf-new/client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
```

The `CN` onto the server is as follows:

```
subject=/C=in/ST=maha/L=mum/O=atos/OU=atos/CN=kafka    
issuer=/C=in/ST=maha/L=mum/O=atos/OU=atos/CN=kafka/emailAddress=abc@gmail.com
```

The `CN` onto the producer is as follows:

```
subject=/C=in/ST=maha/L=mum/O=atos/OU=atos/CN=kaf
```

When I run the command for producing _i.e.

```
$ kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic test --producer.config client-ssl.properties
```

I am able to produce.  But as soon as I add the line below to `server.properties`, *i.e* include ACLS with SSL producing fails:

```
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
```

I created acls with the following command:

```
$ bin/kafka-acls --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:CN=kaf,OU=atos,O=atos,L=mum,ST=maha,C=in --producer --topic hel
```

Fails with the following error:

```
>helo  
 [2017-11-29 12:29:02,845] WARN Error while fetching metadata with 
  correlation id 1 : {hel=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} 
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Please suggest a way to proceed with these configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten to add super.users property which is mandatory which needs to be a typical CN for server.properties.

Adding that solved my issue